# Creating a hash for a large list of values

Tags: java, hash

I have a `Set<Long>`, and I want to create a hash that represents all the values of this `Set`. I'm going to store this hash for comparison later in a file, but not the original Object. I'm wondering about the collisions that `hashCode()` might generate with all these `long` values. Is using `hashCode()` correct here, or should I use some other hashing algorithm?

EDIT: I don't have the object to compare an equals with. I should have said I'm looking for a hash because I don't store the original.

Comment: Hashes will _always_ have collisions.  What are you doing with the hash?

Comment: Do you really believe collisions wont be possible for large numbers, if you override the hashCode() method?

Comment: Are you saying that you're writing your own `List` implementation or that you're wanting to hash an existing `List` class?

Comment: `List` isn't a class.

Comment: I'm using a `HashSet`. I want to compute the hash of all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the updated question:
 Depending on what you want this hash value to be used for, you probably don't want to use hashcode().

Instead you probably want to use a checksum algorithm such as  MD5 or SHA-1.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that is the word I've been looking for. Those should work well for me.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to worry, `hashCode()` is only used to determine the "bin" the object will be put into.  Collisions are OK.  If multiple objects have the same hashcode then they get put in the same bin.  When retrieving an Object, the software again uses the hashcode to get the bin, then walks over the list of elements in that bin and uses the `equals()` method to find the correct Object.

In fact, most of the time, the Hash only has a few bins so potentially thousands of hashcodes will get put in the same bin.

This is all done for you by HashMap or HashSet so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, but I don't have an original object to do an equals with, which is why I'm looking for a unique hash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should always override equals() and hashCode() especially if you are going to store your objects inside a HashMap, or any other types of dictionary type structures.